# How do I remove the white margins along the sides of my HTML email?

Tags: html, email, padding, html-email, margins

This is the issue I'm having right now. There are these margins along the left and right sides of my HTML email as seen here in Mac mail (also visible in Gmail and Thunderbird): http://cl.ly/image/3j133f393Y3M/Screen%20Shot%202013-06-26%20at%201.22.04%20AM.png

What I'm aiming for is a full-width background like this: http://cl.ly/image/1205093I1m34/Screen%20Shot%202013-06-26%20at%201.22.47%20AM.png

My background's width already seems to be set to 100% according to the code:

```
<html>
       <title>AASU VCU</title>
       <body style="margin:0px 0px 0px 0px; padding:0px 0px 0px 0px; font-family: Helvetica, Arial, san-serif; background-color:#fff" bgcolor="#000">
       </body>

    <table bgcolor="#b2151b" style="color:#fff;font-family:Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;font-size:16px;line-height:26px;width:100%;margin:0;padding:0">
    <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%" bgcolor="#b2151b" style="padding:0 40px; color:#fff"; font-family="Helvetica,Arial,san-serif"; font-size:"16px"; line-height="25px"; table-layout="fixed">

    <tbody>
       <tr>
          <td bgcolor="#b2151b" width="450" style="color:#fff;font-family:Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;font-size:16px;line-height:26px">
          <br>
          <br>
    <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="450" bgcolor="#b2151b" border="0" rules="none" frame="border" align="center" style="color:#fff; font-family:Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif; font-size:16px;line-height:26px; border-width:0px 0px 0px 0px; background-color:#b2151b" >

    <tbody>
       <tr>
          <td width="450" valign="top" bgcolor="#b2151b" style="color:#a7abb1;font-family:Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;font-size:16px;line-height:26px">
    <a style="border:none!important;color:#ffffff;text-decoration:none;border-bottom:1px solid #666"><img src="http://f.cl.ly/items/3M3W1U0W1o1P1s3u1Q0C/White_transparent.png" alt="AASU VCU" style="border:none"></a> 
        </td>
        </tr>
        </tbody>
        </table>
```

I tested the code in a browser and the background appears to succeed in stretching to the full width no matter how much or less I resize it. It's only in the mail client(s) that I see these margins. What am I missing?

Comment: can you post more of your html markup? just the 2 table headers are not sufficient to solve your issue.

Comment: Quick and dirty way is to use `* { margin: 0; padding: 0 }` in your stylesheets. It sets all the margins and paddings of ALL elements to zero.

Comment: @LinkinTED - This is HTML email so I don't think I want to use CSS. Although I did change the body style to "margin: 0; padding: 0". Nothing doing.

Comment: Why not use CSS, it's allowed and even better than using `bgcolor`... And you allready use inline-CSS with the `style=""` attribute. Try adding this, right under `<html>`:
`<head>
<style type="text/css">
* { margin: 0; padding: 0; }
</style>
<title>AASA VCU</title>
</head>`

Comment: @LinkinTED - It worked! I used inline CSS and set "margin: 0" and "padding: 0 auto". Thanks a lot!

Comment: @LinkinTED `bgcolor` is better in html email. `background-color` css doesn't work as consistently in all email clients.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest including "border:0px" attribute in the first table element. My rule of thumb is that I set margin, padding and border to 0px when I have no set value for them.

Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

Also, your `</body>` closing tag is right under the `<body>` tag. That might be an issue too.